# Why is it necessary to have 'yield' in this statement from node app?

Tags: node.js, koa

While I was trying to use 'koa-router' module for koa, I saw the example code snippet below.

```
app.get('/users/:id', function *(next) {
  var user = yield User.findOne(this.params.id);
  this.body = user;
});
```

My question is, why does it have `yield` right before it gets user info? Why can't code be something like below without yield? Is there major difference?

```
app.get('/users/:id', function *(next) {
  var user = User.findOne(this.params.id);
  this.body = user;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The function with the asterisk `function *(){}` is a **generator function**, which allows **pausing** and **resuming** flow within the function by using the `yield` keyword.

A generator function without a yield is useless, they go hand in hand.

Behind the scenes in **koa** your **generator** function is being called by the [co](https://github.com/tj/co) library which handles all the asynchronous operations, **abstracting** the **callback / promise** into the library, leaving you with a flatter simpler code.

I created a [screencast](http://knowthen.com/episode-2-understanding-javascript-generators/) on understanding generators that you might find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know koa. But it seems to make use of harmony generators (available from node 0.11).

Essentially the first part is the same as:

```
app.get('/users/:id', function *(next) {
  var self = this;
  User.findOne(this.params.id).then(function(user) {
    self.body = user;
  });
});
```

When the promise the yield takes is resolved, the yield will return the fulfilled value and the program will be resumed from there. The `function *(..)` is (as far as I know) also a special construct that allows the use of yield.

Answer (score 1):

Because the body would be set to a value which won't exist until the future.

You can think of the `yield` here as a kind of `wait` keyword, where the waiting behavior is being handled by the Koa infrastructure. You yield a promise, then Koa waits for the promise to fulfill, then it calls your generator again (well, actually, calls `next()` on the iterator based on the generator), using the promise's resolved value as the argument to `next`, which means it gets assigned to the variable on the left-hand side of the `yield`.

So in this case, you make the DB call, yield the resulting promise to Koa, Koa waits for it to fulfill, then passes back the fulfilled value which is assigned to the variable `user`, and the function runs either until the next yield, or until it falls off the bottom.

It might be clearer if you consider how you would handle **two** asynchronous tasks in the same request:

```
app.get('/users/:id', function *(next) {
    var user = yield User.findOne(this.params.id);
    var data = yield someOtherAsynchronousTaskReturningProimse(user);
    this.body = data;
});
```

In this case, you are "jumping up and down on the trampoline" twice.

Depending on how you choose to think of this, you can sorta kinda treat this as the more readable equivalent of something like

```
function handle(id) {
    User.findOne(id)
        .then(function(user) {
            someOtherAsynchronousTaskReturningPromise(user)
                .then(function(data) {
                    setDataIntoResponse(data);
                });
        });
}
```

I think you'll agree that the so-called "co-routine" based approach is much more readable. Another advantage of this architecture, besides allowing you to write your middleware/handlers in `yield...yield` fashion, is that Koa can go about doing other useful things while it's waiting for the promise you returned to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

KOA uses generator functions to simplify the injection of so-called middlewares. From KOA's website (http://koajs.com/):

> When a middleware invokes yield next the function suspends and passes
>   control to the next middleware defined. After there are no more
>   middleware to execute downstream, the stack will unwind and each
>   middleware is resumed to perform its upstream behaviour.

Example:

```
var app = Koa();

app.use (function* (next) {
    this.body = '{';
    yield next;
    this.body += '}';
});

app.use (function* () {
    this.body += 'Hello World!';
});
```

This webserver will respond with the string '{Hello World!}'. Why? Execution flows into the first generator function, sets body to '{' and pauses at `yield next`. Execution continues with the next generator function and appends 'Hello World!'. That function ends, so execution flows back to where the first one paused, which appends '}'.

In your case however, it's a bit more complicated insofar that yield is used to pass back something other than `next`. In KOA, you may also yield promises, for example. Have a look at this (which I found here: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/12/21/experiments-with-koa-and-javascript-generators/)

```
app.use(function *() {
    var response = yield doHttpRequest('http://example.com/');
    this.body = "Response length is " + response.body.length;
});
```

In this example, `yield` passes back the promise from an asynchronous Http request (done by the helper function doHttpRequest, which is not shown here). KOA pauses the function until the promise is fulfilled, then execution continues with "this.body=...". In your snippet, User.findOne() probably returns such a promise. (Not necessarily; KOA allows you to pass back other kinds of objects, see the docs.)